# Android: Why does .getText return "false"?

Tags: java, android, textview, adapter, gettext

I'm so close to finishing the functions for my app and one thing won't work.

I have an adapter which makes the backgrounds for my views by taking colors I've specified in the color.XML. The function which returns a view with the specified color works excellent.

`textView.setBackground` works great. However, `textView.setText` returns `"false"` in my views and therefore they look like this.

I am trying to get the "android:text" from my TextView in my XML.

What am I missing?

[image]

The code:

```
textView.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(mColorID[position]));
textView.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(mThumbIds[position]));

    return textView;
}

   private Integer[] mColorID = {
       R.color.turquoise,R.color.greenSea,
       R.color.emerald,R.color.nephritis,           
};

    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.id.text_test,R.id.text_test,
        R.id.text_test,R.id.text_test,
};
```

**EDIT: Added the TextView with the ID I would like to get the text from (text_test).**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Hello World!"
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing View ID's and not string resources.  Try changing to this:

```
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
    R.string.text_test,R.string.text_test,
    R.string.text_test,R.string.text_test,
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't specific enough, but as I wrote in the comment above, I want to get the text from the TextView with the ID text_test, please see above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

mContext.getResources().getString()

> returns a localized formatted string from the application's package's
>   default string table

So if your texts are located in file *strings* in your array you should have
R.**string**.text_test,

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't specific enough, but the text I want to get is actually inside of the TextView with the ID text_test, as I have specified (R.id.text_test).  

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_test"
        android:text="Hello World!"
     />

Any suggestion on how to get this text? Thanks.

Comment: For getting text from TextView you sholud  use:
((TextView) context.findViewById(R.id.textview)).getText().toString()
You can use:
textView.setText(((TextView)mContext.findViewById(mThumbIds[position])).getText().toString);